statistical test to compare a single value (mutation number) with a set of mutation numbers
I have a single mutation value of a pathogen for a specific country that is 6. This same pathogen has different values for other countries as 5,7,8,9, and 10. How can I compare the statistical significance of that specific value for the specific country to other values of different countries. I tried paired two-sided t-test but seems like it's not the good option considering I have only a single value in one group.
What would be the best method in this case?
